# What is "ON" in the end of the query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I have got query which looks something like this:

```
...
GO
CREATE TABLE [schema_name].[table_name] (
    [field1] [int] not null,
    [field2] [int] not null,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Some_name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([field1] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [CommonData]
) ON [CommonData]
GO
...
```

The question is what is the "ON [CommonData]"? Why does this occur twice? What is the point of that part and what about [CommonData] - is this something like a default feature or is it custom?

Comment: Documentation for T-SQL would answer this. Hint: [they specify file groups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65596/what-happens-when-you-create-the-primary-key-of-a-table-on-a-different-filegroup), for the constraint and table respectively.

Comment: You probably only need one `ON` as the clustered primary key *is* the table. I *think* all three permutations (of specifying on the table, the clustered index , or both) will lead to the same end result

Comment: @MartinSmith This is true ONLY if you make an assumption about the primary (default) filegroup.

Comment: @SMor no it isn't. I've just tested it. I create a filegroup called `CommonData` - which is *not* the default and specifying in either place gives the same end result in this case

Answer (score 1):

The `ON [CommonData]` is defining the [file group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver15) used for physical storage of the data.

The syntax you use in the question defines it for both the clustered index and the table. These are not in fact two separate entities though. The clustered index *is* the table.

You can omit either one of them and you end up with the same result. The table is created as a clustered index on filegroup `CommonData` and any nonclustered indexes on the table are created on that file group if not explicitly specified otherwise.

i.e. Both attempts below return the same results

```
+--------------+------------+
|     name     |    name    |
+--------------+------------+
| PK_Some_name | CommonData |
| ix_field3    | CommonData |
| ix_field2    | CommonData |
+--------------+------------+
```

---

```
drop TABLE if exists dbo.table_name

go

CREATE TABLE dbo.[table_name] (
    [field1] [int] not null,
    [field2] [int] not null,
    [field3] [int] not null INDEX ix_field3,  /*Not specifying filegroup*/
CONSTRAINT [PK_Some_name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([field1] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
) ON CommonData

CREATE INDEX ix_field2 ON  dbo.[table_name]([field2]) /*Not specifying filegroup*/

SELECT i.name, ds.name
FROM sys.indexes i
JOIN sys.data_spaces ds on ds.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
WHERE object_id = object_id('dbo.table_name')

GO

drop TABLE if exists dbo.table_name

go

CREATE TABLE dbo.[table_name] (
    [field1] [int] not null,
    [field2] [int] not null,
    [field3] [int] not null INDEX ix_field3,  /*Not specifying filegroup*/
CONSTRAINT [PK_Some_name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([field1] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)  ON CommonData
)

CREATE INDEX ix_field2 ON  dbo.[table_name]([field2]) /*Not specifying filegroup*/

SELECT i.name, ds.name
FROM sys.indexes i
JOIN sys.data_spaces ds on ds.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
where object_id = object_id('dbo.table_name')
```